# Arrays em estruturas de condição

Tags: javascript, array, condição

estou com dúvida em relação a este código. Estou estudando js e preciso entender como posso identificar no meu input "letter" os valores que estabeleci no array numbers. Basicamente quero filtrar números e letras. A solução provisória que encontrei foi identificar em uma das condições cada número individualmente do array, mas isso torna a leitura um pouco confusa. Como posso utilizar os valores do meu array na estrutura de condição para serem identificados pelo input?

```
let letter = prompt("Qual a sua letra?");

letter = letter.toUpperCase();

if(letter == "A" || letter == "E" || letter =="I" || letter == "U" || letter == "O" ){
        alert(`Sua letra ${letter} é vogal`)
} 
 else if(letter == "0" || letter == "1" || letter == "2" || letter == "3" || letter == "4" || letter == "5" || letter == "6" || letter == "7" || letter == "8" || letter == "9"  ){
          alert(`Número digitado. Valor inválido`)
 } else { 
    alert(`Sua letra ${letter} é uma consoante`)
      
 }
```

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8702/112052

Answer (score 0):

Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso, uma é através do indexOf, ele vai procurar no array e retornar a posição que foi encontrada, se não encontrar retorna -1
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Uma dica: para testar se é número a função isNaN do javascript, ele testa se uma string não é um numero, então se ela retornar false quer dizer que é um número.

Como ficou com código com essas alterações:

```
let letter = prompt("Qual a sua letra?");
const vogals = ["A", "E", "I", "O", "U"]

letter = letter.toUpperCase();

if(vogals.indexOf(letter) > -1{
        alert(`Sua letra ${letter} é vogal`)
} 
 else if(isNaN(letter) === false{
          alert(`Número digitado. Valor inválido`)
 } else { 
    alert(`Sua letra ${letter} é uma consoante`)
      
 }
```